# How to remove the dots using Jquery Mobile so that all titles can be seen?

Tags: jquery-mobile, formatting, usability

i made an application with Jquery Mobile. I wanna ask, how to remove the dots so that all titles can be seen? Because when I shrink the browser, the title was changed to the dots. I want to make it to be normal. thanks

Here's the screenshoot:
[app](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6MtEMbZDsHCeXg3Y1NKUUFrN0E/edit)

Comment: you might want to prepare a **small** example using http://jsfiddle.net...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it uses the CSS property [`text-overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#text-overflow0) with the value `ellipsis`?

If so, you'd have to overwrite the [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow) property to use `visible`.

Comment: I've tried it, but it had no effect. I added this, white-space: normal !important, but it didn't work properly too.

Comment: and why do you not override the `text-overflow` as suggested? See also http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're asking but I had a similar issue that the headers where being centered and therefore showing dots if they didn't so I  modified the 
/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css file line 1163

```
.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title { margin: .6em 30% .8em;
```

to

```
margin: .6em 0.8em;
```

unnecessary padding since its centered anyway